# Baby Rudin Chapter 9 Exercise 12 d)

Tags: real-analysis

Let $a,b \in \mathbb R$ such that $0<a<b$. Let $ \lambda$ an irrational and $f=(f_1,f_2,f_3)$ a mapping from $\mathbb R^2$ into $\mathbb R^3$ such that:

$f_1(s,t)=(b+a \cos s )\cos t$

$f_2(s,t)=(b+a \cos s )\sin t$

$f_3(s,t)=a \sin s $

Let $g(t)=f(t, \lambda t)$, that is:

$g_1(t)=(b+a \cos t )\cos (\lambda t )$

$g_2(t)=(b+a \cos t )\sin (\lambda t )$

$g_3(t)=a \sin t $

I need to show that $g$ is a 1-1 mapping onto a dense subset of the range of $f$. I've done the 1-to-1 part but I have no clue about the density part. Help is much appreciated.

Comment: It may be helpful for you to know that *all* of the solutions to Baby Rudin may be found [here](http://minds.wisconsin.edu/handle/1793/67009).